# Inspect SVG animation with DevTools

Tags: animation, svg, devtools, keyframe, svg-animate

I've written a small example of SVG animation.

https://codepen.io/mental-dev/pen/YzNvwWR

```
@keyframes{}
```

And trying to inspect it with DevTools > Animations.
But it shows nothing.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: I use Chrome v90 and does not have animation inspector either. I suppose it's a deprecated tool...